# Find an invariant in the minimum algorithm

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, loop-invariants

I have the following simple algorithm to find the smallest element of an array $A$ of numbers:

```
m = A[0];
For i = 0 to A.length() do
    if m < A[i] then
        m = A[i];
    end
end
return m;
```

The complexity of this algorithm is $O(n)$ where $n$ is the length of $A$.

I would like to prove the correctness of this algorithm using an invariant. Yet I don't know which invariant is nice here.
Maybe something like: $m$ is the minimum of the subarray $A[1..k]$.

Comment: I think that invariant works perfectly for this algorithm. What are you stuck on exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The invariant is good (once you fix lots of imprecise things, like the 1..k which is obvious nonsense, and wouldn’t proof correctness. Precision is important. ) The code is broken, so your proof should fail - because it would be an invariant of a correct algorithm, but not *your* code posted here.